# What the distribution of $\overline{X}$?

Tags: probability

A random sample of size $n=15$ is drawn from $EXP(\theta)$ distribution. Find $c$ so that $P(c\overline{X}<\theta)=0.95$ where $\overline{X}$ is the sample mean.

If $X_i\sim EXP(\theta)$ ($i=1,2,\ldots,15$), what the distribution of $\overline{X}$? I confused to determine the distribution of $\overline{X}$. Is it right $\overline{X}$ also exponential distribution?

Comment: It's more statistics than probability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The convolution of $n$ exponential distributions Exp($\theta$) is a Gamma distribution Gamma($n,\theta$).

Notice that, for any $x>0$,
$P[\overline{X}_n<x]=P[X_1+\ldots+ X_n < nx]$

Can you  finish from here?

Here is something that may be [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions) for you.